# Why isn't this output consistent?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skphysicsworld

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    ball=SKShapeNode.init(rectOf: CGSize.init(width: 10, height: 10))
    ball.lineWidth=0
    ball.physicsBody=SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf: CGSize.init(width: 10, height: 10))

    ball.position=CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0)

    self.addChild(ball)
    ball.physicsBody!.velocity=CGVector.init(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    self.physicsWorld.gravity=CGVector.init(dx: 0, dy: -0.01)
}

override func didFinishUpdate() {
    print((-ball.physicsBody!.velocity.dy)/((-ball.position.y)/(-ball.physicsBody!.velocity.dy/2)))
}
```

Output:
1.4310210438517
1.42473254886035
1.42380975809209
1.42285065872957
1.42185899338757
1.42083705265364
1.41978773377494
1.41871330485672
1.41761550240789
1.41649680153093
1.41535815092362
1.41420155874539
1.41302819426671
1.41183908563227
1.41063608544617
1.40941939437473
1.40819085763207
1.4069507476679
1.40569994613022
1.40443912710566
1.40316889163272
1.40189032668562
1.40060389047008
1.39930981002438
1.3980086177394
1.39670135724005
1.39538822941222
1.3940696854372
1.3927454368284
1.39141694745025
1.39008355320803
1.38874607529963
1.387404633016
1.38605934341604
1.38471084197874
1.3833595145688
1.38200513075583
1.3806482372776
1.37928863118993
1.37792691042815
1.37656326127297
1.37519711050934
1.37382946542547
1.37245997303348
1.37108918198904
1.36971714713335
1.36834384140732
1.36696932521041
1.36559404986317
1.36421788447531
1.3628405907902
1.3614627199032
1.36008426490743
1.3587055498073
1.3573263382028
1.35594647229548
1.35456664886424
1.35318668984808
1.35180648065711
1.35042632284601
1.34904599525735
1.3476660886723
1.34628637120676
1.34490655007056
1.34352717817481
1.34214825516409
1.34076956266992
1.33939116967523
1.33801325532258
1.3366358790194
1.33525901699307
1.33388303415708
1.33250717522619
1.33113215378044
1.32975801635423
1.32838414421357
1.32701111306219
1.32563933830281
1.32426758905413
1.3228970477821
1.32152737899811
1.32015835702641
1.3187906447746
1.3174239100656
1.31605782496892
1.31469279153619
1.31332872547715
1.31196566667412
1.31060364476174
1.30924280705312
1.30788285505249
1.30652415898416
1.30516641633863
1.30381010280519
1.30245469794886
1.30110057057794
1.29974752918125
1.29839562271435
1.29704518712955
1.29569584202635
1.29434782499582
1.29300085935135
1.29165497307993
1.29031060050431
1.28896738052348
1.28762545419971
1.28628464369092
1.28494545219929
1.28360736794894
1.28227069316718
1.28093517207214
1.27960129017998
1.27826863586409
1.27693730635726
1.27560735784953
1.27427880765903
1.2729517437664
1.27162582047838
1.27030163963059
1.26897863552402
1.2676570782965
1.26633695769264
1.26501799990428
1.26370099771256
1.26238510002457
1.26107087114903
1.25975778144494
1.25844630568929
1.25713605058639
1.25582726549303
1.2545199510486
1.2532142985786
1.25190968787039
1.2506070928494
1.24930578236314
1.24800566643984
1.24670741716467
1.2454103275286
1.24411490152722
1.24282093247028
1.24152837796215
1.24023751277911
1.23894797792525
1.23765978926466
1.23637336835834
1.23508821404541
1.23380454464686
1.23252247410288
1.23124185212043
1.22996280521175
1.22868503567403
1.22740886288384
1.22613428500731
1.22486131825241
1.22358986779858
1.22231986387838
1.22105136126329
1.21978432499609
1.21851880703641
1.21725460180433
1.21599221524688
1.21473144011458
1.21347187973796
1.21221411146497
1.21095777303452
1.2097027190479
1.20844931114563
1.20719747867042
1.20594738165392
1.20469844572283
1.2034511819688
1.20220555722454
1.20096119970216
1.19971849488758
1.1984772649706
1.19723788720658
1.19599980598168
1.194763183395
1.19352817987756
1.19229471711091
1.19106281527165
1.18983226091906
1.18860334858804
1.18737598223614
1.18615020022484
1.18492615800994
1.18370326664557
1.1824821901473
1.18126221705299
1.1800440041251
1.17882733526295
1.17761200545948
1.17639817230099
1.17518575323393
1.17397537905562
1.17276636590195
1.17155910283505
1.17035303750097
1.16914878960782
1.16794592580321
1.16674436837339
1.16554449620998
1.16434611669584
1.1631490344224
1.16195351186009
1.16075959046708
1.15956728967661
1.15837609488107
1.1571864907997
1.1559983887768
1.15481193627464
1.15362705846645
1.1524435643032
1.15126160240228
1.15008141924748
1.14890240830198
1.14772491731971
1.1465489947245
1.14537455084554
1.14420142232554
1.14302994693818
1.14185984410365
1.14069116689079
1.13952382707432
1.13835806176524
1.13719401276923
1.13603119917212
1.13486985652885
1.13370992203216
1.13255183141009
1.13139511085995
1.13023990357584
1.12908620389238
1.127934266822
1.126783543704
1.1256342626674
1.12448633280742
1.12333992783117
1.12219475935545
1.1210509691241
1.11990897331472
1.11876840125289
1.11762892348344
1.11649134150144
1.11535498031714
1.11422009335586
1.11308654958959
1.11195460207686
1.11082404304846
1.10969508451292
1.10856755814052
1.10744133760351
1.10631663345205
1.1051932802126
1.10407148525381
1.10295093961722
1.10183185080508
1.10071442270647
1.09959823753615
1.09848349978608
1.09737027246644
1.09625821403253
1.09514770757884
1.09403870386851
1.09293104312613
1.0918246789736
1.09071980965244
1.08961649895875
1.08851430175504
1.08741383110463
1.08631497271992
1.08521733042771
1.08412108230306
1.08302626380586
1.08193282975574
1.08084107974195
1.07975033034813
1.07866112950884
1.07757348060101
1.07648712156108
1.0754020108205
1.07431844438794
1.07323621143538
1.07215527155697
1.07107586823756
1.0699979588389
1.06892133623536
1.06784607539401
1.06677218690519
1.06569958056103
1.06462821768929
1.06355833417498
1.06249010324542
1.06142299918557
1.06035736544289
1.05929294551874
1.05823007898104
1.0571685661552
1.05610852822212
1.05504950454562
1.05399209425966
1.05293604546843
1.05188121989181
1.05082789194855
1.04977581929628
1.04872512353203
1.04767566157051
1.04662780743601
1.04558116976211
1.04453571578353
1.04349166441752
1.04244907842211
1.04140792198026
1.0403681047728
1.03932955180006
1.03829232624135
1.03725648956656
1.03622182002787
1.03518841844442
1.03415660504928
1.03312590046257
1.03209666172883
1.03106879877476
1.03004209731434
1.02901676418034
1.0279929134985
1.02697007626195
1.02594874798404
1.02492860655008
1.02391005487805
1.0228924850453
1.02187629986849
1.02086155454579
1.01984801790196
1.01883600167827
1.01782510708346
1.01681555811883
1.01580715778041
1.0148003248251
1.01379450083001
1.01279018517347
1.01178720777491
1.01078553947683
1.00978520974656
1.00878599465751
1.007788142903
1.00679135202765
1.00579594856255
1.00480168967828
1.00380878239448
1.00281723760485
1.00182704655719
1.00083797047239
0.999850118887215
0.998863616922139
0.997878303325356
0.996894477401935
0.995911712883748
0.994930457161549
0.993950227008096
0.992971511393131
0.991993902711504
0.99101749459299
0.990042406525832

Answer (score 0):

Just found lineardamping which determines air friction,the output became consistent after set it to zero